# How do you extract coreferences in CoreNLP 3.6.0? Missing documentation?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run the code found here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html

```
public class CorefExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Annotation document = new Annotation("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He is the president. Obama was elected in 2008.");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("coref chains");
    for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
      System.out.println("\t" + cc);
    }
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("---");
      System.out.println("mentions");
      for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println("\t" + m);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

However, these three imports required aren't found for me:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Mention;
```

I could use these imports instead:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.Mention;
```

But then an annotation is missing, specifically:

```
CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class
```

Additionally, CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values() returns null...

I think the problem is that I am using CoreNLP version 3.6.0. This tutorial is for 3.7.0 I believe. Is there a similar example that uses version 3.6.0? If not, what changes do I need to make? I have a large pipeline set up and I'm not sure how hard it would be to upgrade.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would recommend just upgrading to Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0, it should not cause too many things to break.

One of the main changes is that we created a new package named `edu.stanford.nlp.coref` and put the code from `edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref` into it.

For the most part things should be the same though if you upgrade.

Comment: Okay, I have been assuming that everything would break when I made the change, but I'll go ahead and see. Thanks!